# How to get grand parent record in a Flow element

Tags: visual-workflow

I have the following relationship between 3 objects. (Contact would be the grand parent)

[image: d-paren]

If I have the payment record in a flow element, how can I get the Contact record (without using another query)? I tried using the following but it throws an error.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get individual fields from the contact using flow formula fields with [cross object field references.](https://explorationsintosalesforce.wordpress.com/2015/10/21/cross-object-field-referencing-in-visual-flow/)

You cannot get the contact object itself, without a query.

Comment: In my case, I don't even need to use formula fields, I can simply access any field (E.g. `Payment.Class__r.Contact__r.Email`) and assign to variables, but not the record itself.

Comment: The only way to *get* a record is via a query.  You can create a record variable and assign an id to it, and then set fields on it and use it in an update, if that is what you are after.